# How to count rows in db for each hour?

Tags: mysql

In table are two columns: `Datestamp` like 2012-12-16 with type `date` and `Timestamp` like 12:22:59 with type `time`. Is it possible to get count of rows for each hour for specific day  with 1 sql? On return i need to get 24 numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_table 
WHERE `Datestamp` = '2012-12-16' 
GROUP BY HOUR(`Timestamp`)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT datestamp as day, hour(timestamp) as hour, count(*)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY datestamp, hour(timestamp)
```